# working with a 3D array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'll preface this with the standard "I'm new to C++" statement. This is my first time working with arrays and am having some difficulty.

I understand arrays in general. I also understand initializing the array. Where I am struggling is with printing specific rows/columns from my 3D array. Basically, we have a large array of high and low temperatures for three months. The goal is to print various subsets of the array per user request. [Here](http://cpp.sh/7pob) is the shell of my program. I've entered only 3 days worth of data for starters.

The functions for calculating average, max, and min were provided. Maybe I'm not fully understanding how these functions are operating.

I started with something like this:

```
case 'A':
    cout << "Which month? ('J' for June, 'U' for July, 'A' for Aug)" << endl;
cin >> y;
    switch (y)
    {
    case 'J':
        cout << "The average for June was " << for (i=0; i<DAY; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<1; j++)
            {
                for (k=0; k<XTR; k++)
                {
                    average_array[3][0][2];
                }
            }
        } << endl; break;
```

where I am wanting to call the function average_array to iterate through all (3) days for only month June, and print the result.

I also tried replacing things like:

```
average_array[DAY][MONTH][XTR];
```

or

```
for (i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<1; j++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<2; k++)
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated! Obviously I am going about this entirely the wrong way, and am just not understanding how to reference specific sets of values in the array. The closest our textbook gets to explaining this is iterating through 1D and 2D arrays and printing the result. This is a small assignment, but understanding this is the key to completing our next (and last) large project.

Comment: std::array and std::vector is the "new" way of making things, but it does not hurt to have a solid grasp on C-style arrays.

Comment: Yes, especially if he's trying to `cout << for...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop can't be used as input into cout. You should cout each array value separately like this:

```
cout << "The average for June was ";
for (i=0; i<DAY; i++) {
   for (j=0; j<1; j++){
       for (k=0; k<XTR; k++){
           cout << average_array[3][0][2];
           //to make it a little nicer, use this
           //cout << ", "
       }
   }
} 
cout << endl;
```

However, there are a couple issues even with the above fix:

1. This just prints out the value of `average_array[3][0][2]` many times. If you wanted to print out each value in the array change the `[3][0][2]` to `[i][j][k]`.
2. Your `for (j=0; j<1; j++)` only loops over one value of j, namely 0. There's no reason to have this loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
so for 2. I had it set up as (j=0; j<1; j++) because the month June is in position 0 in the array, correct? My thinking was that this would only iterate through the month of June. When I got down to July, I was going to use (j=1; j<2; j++). Is this still incorrect?

Comment: @d3adlycasanova even if June was at index 0, (it depends on how you set up your array) you'd still just omit the for loop and use `[i][0][k]` because you're never going to change that value.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement defines a (C-style) integer array of arrays of arrays:

```
int a[A][B][C];
```

The variable **a** now refers to an array which consists of arrays of arrays.

Looping through all the values would indeed be:

```
for(int i=0;i<A;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<B;++j){
        for(int k=0;k<C;++k){
            // do whatever....
        }
    }
}
```

If you only wanted a specific index for say the second-most "loop", remove that loop, for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<A;++i){
    for(int k=0;k<C;++k){
        std::cout << a[i][2][k];
    }
}
```